# What causes connect ETIMEDOUT <IP ADDRESS OF AWS ALB>?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, timeout, gatsby, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a front end react application that uses Gatsby for its data layer to generate the static pages of the website. The data layer source is our backend API hosted in AWS ECS Fargate containers behind an Application load balancer. When the build runs we make around 200 requests to an API in parallel and use the response to populate the graphql data layer, which is then passed on the Gatsby page level components through gql queries. (Standard practice).

Most times the builds are running successfully, no issues. But at certain times we are seeing the error;

```
connect ETIMEDOUT <IP>:443


  Error:connect ETIMEDOUT <IP>:443
  
  - node:net:1278 TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]
    node:net:1278:16
  

not finished source and transform nodes - 529.009s
```

The  here is AWS Application load balancer IP. When this error occurs, I have already gone through the AWS access logs on our side, there are no requests during the time. (as it was timeout to connect, I would not expect to see logs).

But, AWS Application Load balancer is auto scalable without any configuration.

Not really sure, why at times we seeing issue and not at other times?

Comment: Hi Anandakumar, Do you find the reason?